# How do I rename a nested key in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, dictionary, rename

I want rename to rename my dict key in mongodb.

normally it works like that `db.update({'_id':id},{$rename:{'oldfieldname':newfieldname}})`

My document structure looks like that

```
{
    'data':'.....',
    'field':{'1':{'data':....},'2':{'data'...}},
    'more_data':'....',
}
```

if i want to set 
a new field in field 1 i do `db.update({'_id':id},{$set:{'field.0.1.name':'peter'}})`

for field two it is 'field'.1.2.name'

i thought with the rename it should be similar but it isn't ... (like `$rename:{'field'.0.1': 2}`

Comment: I don't quite follow what you're trying to do. Can you show an example of a before and after state?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a flexible method for renaming keys in a database

Given a document structure like this...

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("4ee5e9079b14f74ef14ddd2f"),
   "code": "130.4",
   "description": "4'' Socket Plug",
   "technicalData": {
       "Drawing No": "50",
       "length": "200mm",
       "diameter: "20mm"
   },
}
```

I want to loop through all documents and rename technicalData["Drawing No"] to technicalData["Drawing Number"]

Run the following javascript in the execute panel in (the excellent) [RockMongo](http://code.google.com/p/rock-php/wiki/rock_mongo)

```
function remap(x){
    dNo = x.technicalData["Drawing No"];
    db.products.update({"_id":x._id}, {
       $set: {"technicalData.Drawing Number" : dNo},  
       $unset: {"technicalData.Drawing No":1} 
    });
}

db.products.find({"technicalData.Drawing No":{$ne:null}}).forEach(remap);
```

The code will also run in a mongo shell

Comment: hi Chim, i like your suggestion and i tried your code in the mongo shell but it keeps telling me 'can't append to array using string field name [Drawing Number]'   i tried it with a positional operator like $set: {"technicalData.$.Drawing Number" : dNo} but it doesn't seem to understand the positional operator when used in that  context.  it gives message of 'can't append to array using string field name [Drawing Number]'    have you run this in the mongo shell?

Comment: here's a cleaned up version of my prior comment.

hi Chim, i like your suggestion and i tried your code in the mongo shell but it keeps telling me 'can't append to array using string field name [profileId]'.  can you take a look at my code below and see if it looks right?  thanks.

function remap(x){
    pid = x.readingDataSummaries["profileId_"];
    db.profile.update({"_id":x._id}, {
       $set: {"readingDataSummaries.profileId" : pid}
    });
}

db.profile.find({"_id": "1b8bfde2-bb6c-4444-b570-9c12f9002c4f"}).forEach(remap);

Comment: I've tested again just now and the code as above works for me.  mongo v2.02, I think I tested it against v1.8.? previously

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear but it seems you'd like to rename a field name within an array.

The short answer is you can't. As stated in the [docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24rename), $rename doesn't expand arrays to find a matching name. It only works on top level fields.

What you can do to simulate rename is by copying the field and its data to the new name, and then deleting the original field. You might also need a way to account for potentially concurrent writes if you have a lot of writes to that object/field.