# Renaming Fields with Rockmongo

Tags: javascript, mongodb, rename, field, execute

I have many collections of documents in a mongo database that look like this:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("4ee5e9079b14f74ef14ddd2f"),
   "number": 456,
   "date": "2012-02-13"
}
```

I need to rename the field `"created_at"` to `"date"` and I'm using Rockmongo. I think the best way to go about renaming this field would be to use the execute panel in Rockmongo. Basing my code off of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120517/how-do-i-rename-a-nested-key-in-mongodb/8531644#8531644) I tried this:

```
function rename(x){
   db_name.coll_name.update({"_id":x._id}, {
      $rename: {"date":"created_at"}
   });
}

db_name.coll_name.find({"date":{$ne:null}}).forEach(rename);
```

but have been unsuccessful. I have mainly worked with pymongo (and could do it with that), but I think learning this execute panel would be *very* helpful as I continue to use rockmongo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do all of the documents in your collection, you can do it all at once with a multi update, like so:

```
db.coll_name.update({},{$rename:{"created_at":"date"}},false,true);
```

Where "false" is the upsert option, and "true" is the multi-update option.

Hope that helps.

Updated with an example. It even works if the field is already partly renamed, or if the field doesn't exist in all documents:

```
> db.test2.insert({x:12});
> db.test2.insert({x:12});
> db.test2.insert({x:12});
> db.test2.insert({});
> db.test2.update({},{$rename:{"x":"x2"}},false,true);
> db.test2.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f68afb1206dcc69f52c2157"), "x2" : 12 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f68afb2206dcc69f52c2158"), "x2" : 12 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f68afb2206dcc69f52c2159"), "x2" : 12 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f68afb5206dcc69f52c215a") }
```

Comment: Thanks Wes. For some reason this only changed one document, not every one (even with the multi set to true). I'm inclined to think that this has to deal with a bug in Rockmongo. I also tried it with $set to see if it behaved differently, but still the same issue, only one document was updated.

Comment: You put all 4 parameters in? You need (<query>, <update>, false, true)--as far as I know rockmongo just passes through the javascript command. I'll give it a try as I actually use rockmongo myself.

Comment: Worked fine for me: http://imgur.com/zLxMU (all of the test documents were updated)

Comment: I realized I had an unterminated string in my first code--so if you copied it exactly, it wouldn't have worked. Fixed it now.

Comment: Yeah, I used all 4 parameters and it still would only update one document. I'm not sure exactly why that was happening. I ran the same command through pymongo and it worked fine. Thanks for your help, though.